# multiple formulas in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an excel workbook that lists games and their various level of completion.  certain games have achievements and certain games do not.

*example (with achievements)*:

#### Title          Beaten?     Achievements Obtained     Total Achievements     Complete?

Alan Wake     no                                   16                                   67                                 FALSE

*example (without achievements)*:

#### Title          Beaten?     Achievements Obtained     Total Achievements     Complete?

Crysis               no                              n/a                                        n/a                           TRUE

i have an existing formula to check if the **Achievements Obtained** cell matches the **Total Achievements** cell.  If it does, the final column becomes TRUE and recolors the entire row. this formula controls the boolean state of the **Complete?** column.

The issue arises with games that have no achievements that i have not currently beaten.   the **Achievements Obtained** and **Total Achievements** cells match, therefore coloring the row complete.  this should not be the case, if there is a **no** in the **Beaten?** column.

i have an idea that i need to combine a formula, but have no idea how to go about it and haven't had much success with googling.  any help would be  much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't a game be 'complete' only when it has been beaten and all the achievements obtained?

Comment: yes, you are correct.  however there is currently no game, as far as i know, that you can obtain 100% of the achievements without having beaten the game.

Comment: Oh? Almost _all_ the games I've played have many achievements to unlock after actually beating it... One example being the Legend of Zelda. You could beat the game without completing the achievements, and the achievements are even sometimes harder than beating the actual game.

Comment: you misunderstand. there will never be an instance of someone beating the game without at least having an achievement or two.  if you obtain all of the achievements, chances are you've beaten the game.

Comment: Well okay, I can understand that. I guess those games are simply not the type of games I'm used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(C2="n/a", B2<>"no", C2=D2)
```

where `B2` is `Beaten?` value, `C2` - `Achievements Obtained` and `D2` - `Total Achievements`

Answer (score 0):

```
=OR(B2="yes",AND(ISNUMBER(D2),D2=C2))
```

This alternative approach tests for either:
1) explicit marking that the title is marked as being beaten (B2), **- or -**
2) achievements (C2) is equal to total achievements (D2)
to mark the cell true, else false.

Additional benefits to this formula is that it only attempts to compare achievements if it's a number.